# Is there a way to list a personal access token's scopes using Octokit/rest.js?

Tags: octokit, octokit-js

We use Octokit to automate some workflows at work, but most of the time the issues we have is that the users haven't set-up their personal access token correctly, with the right scopes.

We would like to have a check before the app runs, to check if the token given has the right scope and give the engineer a meaningful error message right in the beginning, instead of failing later in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the scopes for a personal access token is listed in the response header, you can access it like this

```js
const { headers } = await octokit.request('HEAD /')
const scopes = headers['x-oauth-scopes'].split(', ')
```

See: [Understanding scopes for OAuth Apps](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/)