# How retrieve organisation's repositories with Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm to working with Github API to trying to **retrieve sha of the last commit** of a specific branch. To be precise, the repository that I target is **managed by an organisation**. I would like to use it to generate a build_id for my webapp. That sounds a good idea in order to host multiple instances with the same state.

First of all, **I create a personal access token** with my personal account *(Settings/Developer settings/Personal acess tokens)* and save it to use it to my script. Thanks to my right access to the targeted repository, I thought that I could use my personal token to access it.

Unfortunately, that didn't work. I could easily retrieve information for my own repository but Github **API returns me an 404 error** when I tried to access to the organisation repositories. Small detail, I'm administrator of the targeted organisation.

Here you could find the nodeJS code that I used to retrieve last commit sha. It works perfectly when I target my own repositories but returns me 404 when I tried to access organisation repositories.

```
const Octokit = require('@octokit/rest');

const octokit = new Octokit({
 auth: process.env.AUTH
});

const fetchCommits = async (owner, repo) => {
  try {
    const params = {
      owner,
      repo,
      page: 1,
      per_page: 1,
    };

    const { data } = await octokit.repos.listCommits(params);
    console.log(data[0]);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};

fetchCommits(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]);
```

Octokit is a famous nodeJS library to communicate with Github API. The `repos.listCommits` method target this endpoint

> https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?page=1&per_page=1',

I'm not forced to use Octokit, I could create my own script to target a specific endpoint if needed but I suppose that a access right issue instead of an endpoint issue.

Like I mention earlier, my script returns me a 404 error. I suppose that is the attending behaviour when you don't have the correct right access to target a specific endpoint.

I read some post about OAuth apps, Github apps or OAuth access but I didn't found a clear way to achieve what I tried to achieve. That seems to be a current use cases for me so it's frustrating for me to not find the correct way to achieve what I want to do.

Do you have an idea to unlock me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make sure that the personal access token you set `AUTH` to has the right permissions? You need at least the repo scope: https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo

You can retrieve the scopes for the current access token as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56010193/206879

Comment: I took a look on the right permissions and indeed that was my problem. Thank you very much for your message. I'm feeling stupid to not took a look on that, that seems obvious for me now!

Comment: Don’t feel stupid, happens to all of us. And GitHub could probably provide more helpful information that just a 404 :)